# Email File Link via .bat file, full link isn't displaying email email body

Tags: email, file, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that will be in the SendTo menu, when you send the file to it, an email is generated with the file hyper-linked in the email's main body.

But, the output is only partial in the email's body, I believe until the first Space in the file's path:

```
<D:\Documents
```

Below is the code that generates the above result.

```
:: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
::  Batchfile : EmailLink.bat
::  Author    : DarkSprout
::  Purpose   : Email File Link via Outlook using Richt-Click 'Send To' menu 
::  NOTE      : Save File in %USERPROFILE%\SendTo
:: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[Jan11]~~

@ECHO OFF
SET _attachmentLink=%~f1
:: ECHO %_attachmentLink%
START MAILTO:?body=^<%_attachmentLink%^>
```

I promise I have looked throughout Stack Overflow for a possible resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the argument if it may contain spaces. And you need a set of empty quotes to satisfy `start`:

```
start "" "mailto:?body=<%_attachmentLink%>"
```

Comment: Genius. Worked a treat. thanks // Sorry I can't Vote Up this answer, I don't yet have the reputation.

Comment: @Dark: You should be able to accept it, though. It's your question after all :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use quotes around the argument

```
@ECHO OFF
SET _attachmentLink=%~f1
:: ECHO %_attachmentLink%
START MAILTO:?body="<%_attachmentLink%>"
```

not sure how you would make it a hyperlink though. (or anything HTML for that matter)

Answer (score 0):

You can't "hyperlink" the attachment because the mail agent will mangle the filename when MIME-encoding the message, and there's no way to know in advance what the mangled filename will be (generally is some random string).

Comment: Unless you mean that you want to upload the file somewhere (e.g. ftp/http server) and insert a hyperlink to the file on the server... in that case it should be feasible somehow.